# Setup Edit page for Custom Content Item on the Front UI

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm busy building a simple CRUD system in Orchard.  I've created a custom Content Item called "Teacher", which has a few fields like name, email address, phone number, etc.

I've create a custom form that uses the Content Item "Teacher" and saves the submission to the database.  Now I can edit this submission from the Admin section, but I would like to make it editable from the Front UI too.  Any idea what the best way is to proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.  Copied the Edit View and Method from Orchard.Core.Contents AdminController to ItemController.

Comment: FYI to anyone doing research on this: it's best not to modify any of the "core" code in Orchard, including any files you download (whether Web or Source). The better thing to do to get this CRUD to work on the front-end UI is to simply create your own module and in a controller implement the functionality of the `~\Orchard.Core\Contents\Controllers\AdminController.cs` file.